# C# XML Dynamic Database File Location

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a VS2017 C# Windows Forms Application that Reads/Writes to an XML file. Currently the file is called with path reference:

```
Application.StartupPath + @"\Database.xml"
```

Which resides in folder path [...\bin\Debug] during development.

I have created an installer that places the file in the *users application data folder*

My question is as follows: During development the ProgramData folder does not exist so i cannot reference this path for the file location. What is the correct way to leave this path location variable and have the path location determined during runtime. Also should I be adding the xml file as part of the project tree (Add -> Existing item...)

Thanks for any guidance given.

Comment: Is [Where to store machine-independent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806356/) informative?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want the file in the ProgramData folder, as the folder you mention is after deploy the location where you put your executable. See it as your closest path, thus with the executable. That way you won't have to worry about a difference between your deployment and development difference.

Regarding your point about adding the file, that doesn't really matter, as long as the location is convenient for you and to call in your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The reason for me wanting to move the file to the ProgramData folder is due to access rights. The application would have to be running as Administrator to bypass any access violation to the Program Files folder.

Comment: It does matter where you store data. Program files or the executable folder may not be writable by users. If it is writeable, multiple users could overwrite each other's data. The executable folder can be erased or replaced if you repair your application. Use [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2); that returns paths that have whatever folders you need.